# Asyncio program quits despite a while True loop in it

Tags: python, python-asyncio

This code just ends almost immediately after I start it.  It's unexpected because I have a `while True` loop in the `run()` function.

```
import asyncio

from binance import BinanceSocketManager
from binance.client import AsyncClient


class Portfolio:
    def __init__(self, async_client: AsyncClient = None):
        self._async_client = async_client
        self.coin_pos = []

    async def run(self):
        asyncio.create_task(self._future_account_listener())

        while True:
            print(f"# of updates: {len(self.coin_pos)}")
            await asyncio.sleep(10)

    async def _future_account_listener(self):
        bsm = BinanceSocketManager(self._async_client)
        async with bsm.futures_socket() as us:
            while True:
                msg = await us.recv()
                print(msg)


async def main():
    async_client = await AsyncClient().create(api_key=API_KEY, api_secret=API_SECRET)

    portfolio = Portfolio(async_client)
    asyncio.create_task(portfolio.run())

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    asyncio.run(main())
```

However, if I replace the code inside the `if __name__ == '__main__':` with

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(main())
loop.run_forever()
```

the code runs as expected.  I'm trying to use `asyncio.run()` as the docs say it's the preferred method to start the main function in the latest version of Python.  What am I doing wrong here?  Or do I just have to use the older method of starting my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `main` method ends by calling `asyncio.create_task(portfolio.run())`. This creates a new asyncio task, but it doesn't wait for it, so your `main` method exits immediately.

You need to tell your code to wait for `portfolio.run` to complete. You can just use `await`:

```
async def main():
    async_client = await AsyncClient().create(api_key=API_KEY, api_secret=API_SECRET)

    portfolio = Portfolio(async_client)
    await portfolio.run()
```